# MPAndroid chart: LimitLine, is it possible to add background drawable of label text?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use this excellent library [MPAndroid Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I would like to know if it's possible to specify a **background drawable** of the label text in LimitLine?

Currently I use it like that:

```
protected void addLimit(int index, float value, String label) {
        LimitLine limitLine = new LimitLine(value, label);
        int color = getCurrentColor(index);
        limitLine.setLineColor(color);
        limitLine.setLineWidth(1f);
        limitLine.enableDashedLine(8f, 8f, 0f);
        limitLine.setLabelPosition(index % 2 == 0 ? LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP :
                LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.LEFT_TOP);
        limitLine.setTextSize(12f);
        limitLine.setYOffset(7f);
        limitLine.setTextColor(color);
        YAxis leftAxis = mChartView.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `LimitLine.class` and its parent `ComponentBase.class`, there is no methods to change its background color. The only styling thing (except you already have in your code) is :

```
public void setTextStyle(Paint.Style style) {
    this.mTextStyle = style;
}
```

And as you might know `Paint.Style`  is `FILL`,  `STROKE`, `FILL_AND_STROKE`.
So I am afraid there is no possibility to change background color.